# L'aggettivo "allibito" ha sempre una connotazione negativa?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adjectives

Ho cercato il significato di "allibito" nel dizionario e ho trovato:

> Esterrefatto, sbigottito, assalito da un intenso ed improvviso stupore.

Ma "stupore" vuol dire

> grande meraviglia

e si può provare meraviglia come un sentimento gradevole. Comunque, io credo di aver letto la parola "allibito" soltanto in frasi con senso negativo. Per esempio:

> Sono rimasto allibito di fronte a tanta ingratitudine.

Dunque, la mia domanda è: l'aggettivo "allibito" ha sempre una connotazione negativa?

Fonte: [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/allibito).

Comment: *Meraviglia* non è di per sé associata alla gradevolezza.

Comment: @egreg: Sì, lo so. Semplicemente volevo dire che "provare meraviglia" può a volte essere associato a un sentimento gradevole, ma non so se sia lo stesso per "essere o rimanere allibito".

Comment: Bella domanda, siccome non so rispondere attendo anche io risposte! Anche a me vengono in mente solo frasi in cui quell'aggettivo è usato in un'accezione negativa.

Answer (score 1):

Che dizionario hai consultato? Il Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/allibire/) non sembra lasciare molto spazio a usi positivi, come fa pensare anche l'etimo della parola, che è lo stesso di “livido” (aggettivo), per la paura o simili.

Comment: E, anche se non rientra nella domanda, anche “esterrefatto” (della stessa famiglia di “terrore” e “atterrire”) denota chi ha un colorito terreo (da cui la parola), in genere per la paura.

Comment: La fonte è [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/allibito). Hai accennato un fatto interessante: l'etimologia di "allibire" mostra che il suo origine è "essere livido". Questo sembra indicare che "allibito" abbia sempre una connotazione negativa (ma è anche curioso notare "meravigliarsi" come sinonimo di "allibire" nel [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/allibire_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)).

Answer (score 1):

Al di là di quello che dicono i dizionari, 'allibito' non è sinonimo di 'meravigliato', ma, piuttotto, di 'basito'.

È chiaro che sia nell'essere 'basito' che nell'essere 'allibito' esiste una componente di meraviglia, ma è una meraviglia che, però, lascia sconcertati in senso critico.

:)