# "Sembra indicare che" + indicativo o congiuntivo?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood

Dopo l'espressione "sembra indicare che" si deve usare il congiuntivo o l'indicativo? Questo dubbio mi ha assalito mentre scrivevo un commento a questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/3664/707). Là ho scritto

> Questo sembra indicare che "allibito" abbia sempre una connotazione negativa

cioè, ho usato il congiuntivo. Non so però se la frase corretta sia

> Questo sembra indicare che "allibito" ha sempre una connotazione negativa

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Comment: Il congiuntivo è giusto. L'indicativo non è sbagliato, ma il *sembra* è indicatore di un'opinione e non di certezza, quindi preferirei il congiuntivo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non considero scorretto l'indicativo, tuttavia suona un po' male per via del verbo reggente *sembra*, il quale introduce un'opinione più che una certezza.

Con i verbi di opinione il congiuntivo è meglio; naturalmente quando si può:

> sembra che domani farà bel tempo
>   sembra che stia tornando il bel tempo

Al futuro si adopera l'indicativo, senza esitazioni: la forma

> sembra che domani possa fare bel tempo

è corretta, ma affettata.

La forma *sembra che sta tornando il bel tempo* mi lascia l'orecchio ferito, sebbene sia una forma molto comune nel parlato: l'uso del congiuntivo purtroppo regredisce. Cerchiamo almeno di rallentarne la scomparsa, di più è difficile fare.

Comment: Tutto giustissimo, ma non stai affrontando veramente la domanda specifica. La presenza di una doppia subordinata (la seconda delle quali – quella su cui verte la domanda – retta da “indicare”, che non è di per sé un verbo esprimente opinione) non potrebbe cambiare qualcosa?

Comment: @DaG *Il vento sembra indicare che il tempo potrebbe cambiare*; useresti l'indicativo qui? Credo di no. Dunque *sembra indicare* è una costruzione che implica incertezza.

Comment: Grazie, egreg, non volevo smentirti: mi stavo proprio chiedendo se “sembra indicare che” si costruisca automaticamente come una normale frase con “sembra”, nonostante la doppia subordinazione (e il fatto che una frase ha un normale soggetto mentre l'altra è impersonale). Non dico affatto di no: ho solo le idee poco chiare (pure perché nell'ultimo esempio è spuntato anche un condizionale :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

Sia 'abbia' che 'ha' sono corretti lì, il congiuntivo differendo dall'indicativo solo perché lascia un'alea di incertezza sull'asserzione; alea che, in un'ipotetica conversazione, consente all'assertore di negare l'asserzione senza doversi scusare, se del caso, di aver affermato una corbelleria.

:)

Comment: Che significa *alea*, secondo te?

Comment: @egreg Significa 'grado di incertezza', ciò che a rigore indurrebbe a pensare che 'alea di incertezza' sia un pleonasmo.

Answer (score 1):

Te la metto giù più facile: con i verbi di opinione (penso, credo, mi immagino, mi sembra) quando si riferiscono ad un'altra persona o ad una situazione usa sempre il congiuntivo e vai sul sicuro! Esempi:
*Mi sembra che tu sia una brava studentessa.

Tutto sembra indicare che la crisi economica vada peggiornado.*

Ricordati che i verbi di opinione quando si riferiscono a se stessi richiedono il "di  + infinito":
*Mi sembra di aver fatto progressi nell'apprendimento dello spagnolo.*

Comment: Grazie, Marco! Ho corretto il mio post. Anche tu puoi correggere gli errori nei post con la funzione "edit".

Answer (score 0):

Tutti questi dubbi sono legittimi. In breve, la forma col congiuntivo assegna semplicemente alla frase un tono più "alto". Chi scrive per un tema scolastico fa probabilmente meglio a errare sul lato di usare un congiuntivo in più, ma l'italiano non funziona esattamente così.

La strategia usata nelle scuole italiane per spiegare il congiuntivo fa acqua da tutte le parti. Io parlerei senza mezzi termini di "fantagrammatica". Se la grammatica deve spiegare come funziona la lingua, la storiella del congiuntivo come "modo dell'ipotesi, del timore, della paura e bla, bla, bla" semplicemente non regge. È facilissimo costruire frasi dove il congiuntivo non ci starebbe (in accordo a quella regola), ma gli italiani avvertono che, a orecchio, "ci sta" (pur non sapendolo spiegare ovviamente).

L'uso del congiuntivo italiano è un retaggio del latino ed è legato prevalentemente alla possibilità di conferire ai propri scritti un tono più elevato qualora il registro lo richieda.

Ho scritto un articolo in proposito che dovrebbe dissipare la maggior parte dei dubbi: https://www.lavocedinewyork.com/arts/lingua-italiana/2019/10/25/il-congiuntivo-italiano-cari-studenti-stranieri-attenti-alla-fantagrammatica/

Comment: Luca, non mi sembra il massimo “spammare” varie domande con la stessa risposta e lo stesso link a un tuo articolo...

Comment: @DaG Perché no? Sono tutte domande distinte e il mio articolo l'ho scritto proprio per rispondere a quelle domande e per portare un po' di chiarezza rispetto alla fantagrammatica "insegnata" nelle scuole sull'argomento. Non sto spammando. Sto rispondendo con dovizia di particolari. Se qualcosa che ho scritto nell'articolo non ti torna, discutiamone.

Comment: Grazie per l'invito, ma come scrivo anche altrove, questo sito non è dedicato a commentare tuoi articoli su altri siti.